# Fail to pull data from SQLite database and display in activity

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a SQLiteHelper source file which I use to create database and all that. I have another source file which needs to instantiate the database, pull data and display to the UI. However, when I launch the app on the emulator, the app crashes. I am not sure what's wrong. No errors are given in the source files.

RestaurantDB source file

```
package com.demostudio.restaurants;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class RestaurantDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

static final String dbName = "RestaurantDB";
static final Integer dbVersion = 1;

static final String restaurantListTable = "RestaurantList";
static final String colRestaurantID = "RestaurantID";
static final String colRestaurantName = "RestaurantName";
static final String colRestaurantStore = "StoreNo";

public RestaurantDB(Context context) {
super(context, dbName, null, dbVersion);
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

String newTableSQL = 
        "CREATE TABLE "+
        restaurantListTable+
        " ("+colRestaurantID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
        colRestaurantName+" TEXT NOT NULL, "+
        colRestaurantStore+" TEXT NOT NULL "+
        ");";
db.execSQL(newTableSQL);

ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put(colRestaurantName, "Restaurant AAA");
cv.put(colRestaurantStore, "1");
db.insert(restaurantListTable, null, cv);

cv.put(colRestaurantName, "Restaurant BBB");
cv.put(colRestaurantStore, "2");
db.insert(restaurantListTable, null, cv);

db.close();

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

AllRestaurants source file

```
package com.demostudio.restaurants;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class AllRestaurants extends ListActivity {
 RestaurantDB db = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_listview);  
 db=new RestaurantDB(AllRestaurants.this);    
onPostExecute( ) ;
}

private Cursor doQuery() {
return(db.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT colRestaurantID AS _id, colRestaurantName, colRestaurantStore "
+ "FROM RestaurantListTable ORDER BY colRestaurantName", null));

}

public void onPostExecute( ) {
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    adapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_all_restaurants,
            doQuery(), new String[] {
        RestaurantDB.colRestaurantName,
        RestaurantDB.colRestaurantStore },
        new int[] { R.id.title, R.id.value },
        0);
    }
else {
    adapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_all_restaurants,
            doQuery(), new String[] {
        RestaurantDB.colRestaurantName,
        RestaurantDB.colRestaurantStore },
        new int[] { R.id.title, R.id.value });
    }


setListAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

activity_listview XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

activity_all_restaurants XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
android:id="@+id/title"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/value"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:textStyle="bold"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Log file

> 12-13 14:08:52.805: W/Trace(3861): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   12-13 14:08:52.805: W/Trace(3861): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   12-13 14:08:54.795: D/dalvikvm(3861): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 68K, 7% free 2670K/2860K, paused 139ms, total 143ms
>   12-13 14:08:54.826: I/dalvikvm-heap(3861): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.796MB for 1127536-byte allocation
>   12-13 14:08:54.946: D/dalvikvm(3861): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 5% free 3770K/3964K, paused 112ms, total 112ms
>   12-13 14:08:55.145: D/dalvikvm(3861): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 5% free 3785K/3964K, paused 12ms+27ms, total 203ms
>   12-13 14:08:55.618: D/AndroidRuntime(3861): Shutting down VM
>   12-13 14:08:55.618: W/dalvikvm(3861): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)
>   12-13 14:08:55.715: E/AndroidRuntime(3861): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   12-13 14:08:55.715: E/AndroidRuntime(3861): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.demostudio.restaurants/com.demostudio.restaurants.AllRestaurants}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
>   12-13 14:08:55.715: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
>   12-13 14:08:55.715: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
>   12-13 14:08:55.715: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
>   12-13 14:08:55.715: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
>   12-13 14:08:55.715: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   12-13 14:08:55.715: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   12-13 14:08:55.715: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
>   12-13 14:08:55.715: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   12-13 14:08:55.715: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   12-13 14:08:55.715: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>   12-13 14:08:55.715: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
>   12-13 14:08:55.715: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   12-13 14:08:55.715: E/AndroidRuntime(3861): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
>   12-13 14:08:55.715: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:303)
>   12-13 14:08:55.715: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.init(CursorAdapter.java:174)
>   12-13 14:08:55.715: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.(CursorAdapter.java:151)
>   12-13 14:08:55.715: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at android.support.v4.widget.ResourceCursorAdapter.(ResourceCursorAdapter.java:93)
>   12-13 14:08:55.715: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:89)
>   12-13 14:08:55.715: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at com.demostudio.restaurants.AllRestaurants.onPostExecute(AllRestaurants.java:27)
>   12-13 14:08:55.715: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at com.demostudio.restaurants.AllRestaurants.onCreate(AllRestaurants.java:18)
>   12-13 14:08:55.715: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
>   12-13 14:08:55.715: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
>   12-13 14:08:55.715: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
>   12-13 14:08:55.715: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     ... 11 more

I previously put listview with the two textviews in the same XML file, but it didn't work. So now I put it in a separate XML file, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Instantiate a database created by SQLiteHelper source file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13832824/instantiate-a-database-created-by-sqlitehelper-source-file)

Comment: where u are calling `onPostExecute(Void arg0)` method?

Comment: Yes, but I am not getting any answers there that can help me resolve this.

Comment: @JYLim where u are calling onPostExecute(Void arg0) method?

Comment: I followed the sample code. I don't know what to use to substitute that method. Is that why the app doesn't work?

Comment: @JYLim : see my answer which my help u more

Comment: you dont have a listView with id attribute android.R.id.list is the problem so why dont u use a list view in your xml file whose id is android.R.id.list

Comment: I added the listview in my activity_all_restaurants XML file, but it still doesn't work. Is it because of the two textviews I have in the XML file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `onCreate()` of your helper, you have:

```
String newTableSQL = 
    "CREATE TABLE "+
    `+
    " ("+colRestaurantID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
    colRestaurantName+" TEXT NOT NULL, "+
    colRestaurantStore+" TEXT NOT NULL "+
    ");";
```

Notice how you are concatenating strings to create the full statement. The resulting SQL will be:

```
CREATE TABLE RestaurantList (RestaurantID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, RestaurantName TEXT NOT NULL, RestaurantStore TEXT NOT NULL );
```

based upon your values for `restaurantListTable`, `colRestaurantID`, `colRestaurantName`, `colRestaurantStore`.

However, in your `rawQuery()` call, your SQL is this:

```
SELECT colRestaurantID AS _id, colRestaurantName, colRestaurantStore FROM RestaurantListTable ORDER BY  colRestaurantName
```

Notice that your column names in the `rawQuery()` SQL have `col` in front of them, which you will not have in your `CREATE TABLE`. This will not work, as you need the column names to be consistent.

Whether you change your `CREATE TABLE` statement or your `SELECT` statement is up to you.

Comment: Thanks. This works. However, I have db.close(); in my onCreate for the database. How do I open the database in my activity? Apparently getReadableDatabase can't open the database. I can't put db.open() neither.

Comment: @JYLim: "Apparently getReadableDatabase can't open the database" -- `getReadableDatabase()` is how you open the database, for read operations. Use `getWritableDatabase()` if you need to additionally perform write operations.

Answer (score 0):

You did it again. If you need the DB instantiation a field, change `RestaurantDB db=new RestaurantDB(AllRestaurants.this);` to `db=new RestaurantDB(AllRestaurants.this);`

Comment: In fact I did change it in my latest source file, but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
private Cursor doQuery() {
return(db.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT colRestaurantID AS _id,    colRestaurantName, colRestaurantStore "
+ "FROM RestaurantListTable ORDER BY colRestaurantName", null));
}
```

I should use the below instead:

```
private Cursor doQuery() {
return(db.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT RestaurantID AS _id, RestaurantName, StoreNo "
+ "FROM RestaurantList ORDER BY RestaurantName", null));
}
```